# Show Bootstrap Alert on AJAX request error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple AJAX request that updates some PHP session variables based on some selections in a table. If there's an error with the AJAX request I change the colour of the table row that they selected (it usually changes to green if they select 'Yes' and red if they select 'No'). This is all working well.

I would now like to display one of the dismissible Bootstrap alerts on the screen as well, like in their example:

```html
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
</div>
```

but I'm not sure how I can cause this to be displayed when there's an error with the AJAX request. Here's my script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button.btn-success').click(function() {
    var refreshItemID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    console.log(refreshItemID);
    // Create a reference to $(this) here:
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('updateSelections.php', {
      refreshItemID: refreshItemID,
      selectionType: 'yes'
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (data.error) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log('something was wrong with the ajax request');
        $this.closest('tr').addClass("warning");
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else {
        console.log('update successful - success add class to table row');
        $this.closest('tr').addClass("success");
        $this.closest('tr').removeClass("danger");
        //$(this).closest('tr').attr('class','success');
      }
    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      console.log('ajax request failed');
      // no data available in this context
      $this.closest('tr').addClass("warning");
    });
  });
});
```

You can see it adds a warning class to the table row if there's an error:

```
$this.closest('tr').addClass("warning");
```

but I'm not sure how to extend this to also add a dismissible alert (and how to control the positioning of that alert)?

Comment: use this bootstrap notify [CLICK HERE](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g. add the html code of the alert above or under your table and add `style="display:none"` to the alert div. Also set an id, like `id="alert_ajax_error"` to that div.

Now the fail callback should look like this:

```
.fail(function(xhr) {
  console.log('ajax request failed');
  // no data available in this context
  $this.closest('tr').addClass("warning");

  //make alert visible
  $("#alert_ajax_error").show();
});
```

In case of success hide alert with `$("#alert_ajax_error").hide();`

Answer (score 4):

Set alert div default display:none and inside ajax call success / file / error you can show alert using below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('button#alertshow').on('click', function() {
    var msg_type = $("#msgtype").val();
    ShowAlert(msg_type, 'Message Content', msg_type);
  });


  function ShowAlert(msg_title, msg_body, msg_type) {
    var AlertMsg = $('div[role="alert"]');
    $(AlertMsg).find('strong').html(msg_title);
    $(AlertMsg).find('p').html(msg_body);
    $(AlertMsg).removeAttr('class');
    $(AlertMsg).addClass('alert alert-' + msg_type);
    $(AlertMsg).show();
  }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="alertshow">Show alert</button>
<select id="msgtype">
  <option value="warning">Warning</option>
  <option value="info">Info</option>
  <option value="success">Success</option>
  <option value="danger">Danger</option>
</select>
<div class="alert alert-dismissible" role="alert" style="display:none;">
  <strong>Warning!</strong> 
  <p>Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.</p>
</div>
```